# How to save user input from EditText to a variable to be used on a different Activity

Tags: java, android, xml

I have an edit text in Android Studio which I want a user to enter a name which can then be stored as a variable. I then want to add this variable to a textview in my main activity.

Right now all a have is a blank activity with an edit text and button to save the user input as a variable.

**Edit**

Ok, I am going to change my approach. In my main activity, I have two text views. If I changed them to edit texts, then how would I save them from the main activity without a save button so that what the user typed would still be there?

Comment: What about passing the text as string to the intent which you open activity? Using intent.putExtra("username", editText.getText().toString())

Comment: I need to change the text view from a different activity, would this work?

Comment: you can override the onPause() and onDestroy() methods then save the edit text values to variables within these methods so that when the user exits or presses back to exit the activity the data is saved. Use the shared preference as described by @Kushtrim below

Comment: How would you get the string from the edit text to the variable?

Answer (score 2):

Save it in [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) and then retrieve it from the other activity.

To save a String in shared preferences, you can create a method like the following:

```
public static void setUsername(Context context, String username) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("myAppPackage", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString("username", username);
    editor.commit();
 }
```

To retreive it :

```
public static String getUsername(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("myAppPackage", 0);
    return prefs.getString("username", "");

 }
```

**Edited:**
In the activity which contains the EditText, you can call the method as follows:
*setUsername(this,myEditText.getText().toString());*

And in the Activitiy that contains the TextView:
*myTextView.setText( getUsername(this) );*

Comment: Yeah but don't call the same method.  Create another one with a different key,   for example "password", instead of "username'

Comment: In the last line of the retreiving method it says "Cannot return a value from a method with void result type"

Comment: Do I need to change anything in this code or should it work by itself?

Comment: Yeah, forgot to change the return type when i copy/pasted from the set method. It'll work now.

Comment: O, sorry, I think I have been misusing the word save. I don't know how to set the edit text data to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

you ça use `edit.getText().toString()` tout get the user input.

To launch new activity and pass the string to it use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("key", theString);
startActivity(intent);
```

**EDIT**

To be more easy you should add a button to your layout so when the user press that button you can launch the next activity with the string.
This should go into your activity

```
public class BlankActivity implements OnClickListener {

     private EditText mEditText;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

          //find editText
          mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.your_edit_text_id);
          //listen button
          findViewById(R.id.your_button_id).setOnClickListener(this);

     }

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
          String theString = mEditText.getText().toString();
          Intent intent = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
          intent.putExtra("key", theString);
          startActivity(intent);
     }


}
```

Comment: Where would all this go? intent shows as a unknown symbol and getString is invalid.

Comment: mEditText is underlined red and says "{ expected " (private class EditText mEditText;)

Comment: I do a typo. It should be `private EditText mEditText`